# How to get all pixels (coordinates) of an image

Tags: java, arrays, image, image-processing, pixel

So I'm developing a game in java (Asteroids game) and I need to detect a collision between the player's bullet and an asteroid.
So in order to detect the collision I wanted to find each pixel of the asteroid image (some of it is transparent and its not a geometric shape) and check if the bullet is in those coordinates,
but I couldn't find a way to retrieve all the pixels of an image (that are not transparent)

[The asteroid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhsMP.jpg)

I need something like this (pseudo):

```
Point [] nonTransparentPixels;
nonTransparentPixels= getPixels();

if(nonTransparentPixels.Contains(playerBullet.position))
    doCollision();
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't "it hit the circle" precise enough? How possible it is for the bullet to enter one of those concave regions and not hit the asteroid within another 3-4 frames?

Comment: you mean if the bullet enters [this zone for example](https://imgur.com/WYFraFC), is enough to detect a collusion?

Comment: Exactly, would it be sufficient? And the calculation would also be *a lot* faster: you'd just need to check whether the distance between the center of the image and the bullet is less than the radius of the circle.

Comment: I get you, but of course its important I mean lets imagine a scenario where a bullet is entering "that zone"- it'll disappear (after a collusion I want the bullets to disappear) before it actually touched the asteroid and the collusion is correct but also false- they *will* collide but not just yet

Comment: That's ok. I was just wondering whether such a distinction was important when it would be possible to reach a compromise that will be simpler to write and have better performance. I see that's not acceptable, and that's fine. I'll let others take it from here to answer the actual question you were asking :)

Comment: Side note: "collusion" means underhanded corrupt cooperation. Unless your asteroids and bullets are involved in some underhanded deals, I'm fairly sure you mean "collision".

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit my post

Comment: Perhaps use a `Polygon`, `Area` or other `Shape` subclass, which has some very useful `contains(....)` and `intersects(...)` methods. If your shapes are as simple as the one in your image, you could easily recreate those programmatically. Taking an arbitrary image and create/"trace" such an `Area` is harder, but also possible.

Comment: have some documentation to give me? :)

Comment: Read the standard JavaDoc, or see the [Java 2D tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html). PS: If your game graphics happen to be created in Photoshop using paths, [my project can read those paths and create such `Shape`s](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/wiki/Photoshop-Clipping-Path-support).

Comment: Thanks! I'll go check it

Comment: has this discussion come to a conclusion? -- you tagged `image-processing` so I'll assume you don't have vector data, but raster data. -- if you have two "masks" (where alpha channel more than zero), binary-and them. literally an intersection. test if the result is empty or not (count nonzero pixels). don't use outlines. your example picture is an outline. -- look at OpenCV.

Comment: What is openCV?